# Extract information from a layer underneath of a buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a line layer (bus route) and I created an one-mile buffer around it.
Now I want to extract information (population/employment) from the census layer underneath of the buffer area only.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange and thanks for taking the tour. Please edit your question to include more information about your data and what you've attempted so far, as well as your desired output. Also check out Clip, Select by Location, and Intersect Analysis. You will probably need to perform some calculations based on the buffer area as the population represents the full block group, tract, or other Census-based geometry.

Comment: Thank you; clip worked for me. I was able to clip the census layer from the buffer layer.

Comment: Great. Please feel free to add the answer describing what resolved your issue (self-answers are OK here) so that future users can find assistance from this post.